# Convert ISO3 codes to real country name in grails

Tags: grails, converters, gsp, iso

My goal is to convert a country code like 'HRV' to 'Croatia'

In my app the user select is own country using the tag `g:countrySelect`, who return me the in the value field the `iso3` code.

Now i need to show his state in my app, but i want to display the entire country name.

I tried to do something like this:

> Locale.availableLocales.find{it.ISO3Country ==
>   userCountryCode}.displayCountry

But i get this error:

> Couldn't find 3-letter country code for CS

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails provides tag for this:

```
<g:country code="hrv"/>
```